# How to make your own Granary® flour from existing ingredients?

Tags: bread, flour

This flour which is widely available in the UK is harder to obtain elsewhere and also appears to be surrounded in some secrecy.

Does anyone have an approximation of the ingredients/substitutes and proportions?

https://www.hovis.co.uk/granary-wholemeal
"Granary® is not just a type of bread. The ® is there for a reason. It’s a brand and registered trademark of Hovis®. So if it’s not Hovis® it’s not Granary®. The Benedictine Monks of Burton Abbey discovered that slowly toasting wheat flakes used in their brewing process offered a distinctive malty taste, which is what gives our loaf its unique flavour today"

Comment: BTW your link seems to be dead... perhaps you want to replace it with this one? https://www.hovis.co.uk/granary-wholemeal

Comment: I'm wondering if the ingredients are listed in descending order (so telling ust that Flour and water are in 50/50 ratio) and if the 9% next to Malted flakes means it content in the whole mix or just in the Original Granary Blend

Comment: The original link works, but it's a lot of scrolling. I swapped it to one that just hits a single loaf. they don't seem to list the flour separately, even though you can buy it in any supermarket here.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY how do you know it's 50/50 (100% hydration) since flour is first, flour >= water so it could be any hydration 100% and below.

Comment: Also since oil is the only fat, it would be possible to work out the fat/carb ratio using the nutritional information (2.4g fat to 39.8g carbs)

Comment: @stan Good point, I got fixated and mixed 50% hydration and content ratio.

Answer (score 2):

According to Waitrose:

https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/products/hovis-granary-bread-flour/476719-729900-729901

Wheat Flour (with added Calcium, Iron, Niacin, Thiamin), Wholemeal Wheat Flour, Malted Wheat Flakes (17%), Wheat Protein, Malted Barley Flour

So that's:

- white flour, with vitamins for no culinary reason
- wholemeal flour
- 17% malted wheat flakes
- wheat protein because bread needs strong flour (high in gluten)
- malted barley flour

The protein is 14.9%, which definitely qualifies as strong.

Note also:

- 62.9% carbs (of which 1.7% sugar), 1.8% fat, 7.5% fibre, 14.9% protein, hence 12.9% moisture/ash

The own brand product is not the same:

https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/products/waitrose-duchy-strong-malted-grain-bread-wheat-flour/430555-60573-60574 - brown flour, malted wheat flakes, barley malt flour, wheat bran

- 68.4% carbs (of which 3.2% sugar), 1.6% fat, 4.3% fibre, 13.5% protein, hence 12.2% moisture/ash

We might like to compare other bread flours:

- white - 67.4% carbs, 14.9% protein, 2.8% fibre https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/products/waitrose-white-bread-flour/006224-2744-2745
- Canadian very strong wholemeal - 57.0% carbs, 15.8% protein, 11.7% fibre https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/products/waitrose-stoneground-bread-wholemeal-flour/051804-25784-25785
- brown - 72.3% carbs, 12.7% protein, 6.1% fibre https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/products/essential-strong-brown-bread-flour/666913-94660-94661

I think there is nothing at all special in any kind of way about 'Granary', it's just a brand name that Hovis license.

What you are looking at here is either brown flour (which has more bran than white flour, less than wholemeal) or a mix of white + wholemeal, malted wheat flakes, and malted barley flour

Hovis are helpfully specific about the % of malted wheat flakes - 17%. You can buy these in many countries, e.g. https://shop.kingarthurbaking.com/items/malted-wheat-flakes-2-lb

I believe that Hovis makes cheap mass-produced food as a first priority, and I believe that the malted barley flour is in fact a cheap-out. These should be malted barley flakes in fact. There are various forms of barley malt depending on whether they are sprouted or what not, but some form of barley malt will be available pretty much everywhere in the world.

Hovis protect their trademark, but 'brown bread with malt flakes' is nothing special at all, and anyone can make it....